# What's would be the best way of handling this data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a big chuck of data that I'm currently trying to sort into distinct fields. I've been able to get this into lists, structured like:

```
lst = ['A','B','C']
```

I've been iterating through the resultant lists (10,000 or so), and appending them into dataframes:

```
newdf = pd.DataFrame()
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(lst)).transpose()   
newdf = pd.concat(newdf,df)
```

While this has worked I've not assigned these column headers to the data, but this would be useful as there are two distinct layouts to the data. some are structured like:

```
['C', 'B', 'A']
```

So some of the data ends up in the wrong column. I was trying to figure out a way to sort it into the respective columns using the headers. To make this more of a challenge, the data varies considerably in length, so one is:

```
['C','B','A','F']
```

The other:

```
['A','B','C','D','E',F']
```

Or a variety of this, I'm a bit stuck on this, I've tried pre-defining a Dataframe to include all possible columns (15) and creating a dataframe the data 'types'.

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B','C','D','E','F'])
    if Data1:
         l = pd.Series(Data1)
         dfappend = pd.DataFrame(l,columns['A','B','C','F']).transpose()
    elif Data2:
         l = pd.Series(Data2)
         dfappend = pd.DataFrame(l,columns['A','B','C','D','E','F']).transpose()
    df = pd.concat([df, dfappend])
```

But where the data ends up as a different length, I'm getting a length error:

```
AssertionError: 15 columns passed, passed data had 11 columns
```

I feel there's something I'm missing, or whether I could handle this in another way.

Comment: the question is quite unclear, not sure what you're trying to do

Comment: I was trying to figure out a way to sort the data so that each item in the list, was appended into the dataframe by the matching column header.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve it by creating dict

```
if Data1:
   l = ['A','B','C']
   dictlist = ['A','B','C','D','E','F']
else Data2:
   l = ['C','D','E','F']
   dictlist = ['C','D','E','F']
zippeddict = dict(zip(dictlist,l))
df = pd.DataFrame(zippeddict ,index=[0])
```